# setStatus update sales_order's status but sales_order_grid's status in 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I have the following script in custom module to change an order from processing to a custom order's status

```
$order->setStatus(\MyNamespace\Mymodule\Model\Order::STATUS_PRINTED);
$this->orderRepository->save($order);
```

i found that the status field in sales_order is updated, but the status field in sales_order_grid is not updated (occur in magento 2.2.6 commerce edition, but ok in 2.3 ce edition).

Anyone has idea what is the possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using magento226. I tested it for the situation you said, and there is no such situation. can you try this code and let me see what happens.

```
            // test code
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderRepository = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::class);
            $orderId = "xxxxx";
            $order = $orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $order->setStatus('test');
            $order->save();
            //$orderRepository->save($order);
```

Comment: i don't know why 2.2.6 need me run a command to update the column at sales_order table bin/magento cron:run